# aligning multiple signals with same shape but varying x's and y's (time and voltage)

Tags: python, alignment, signal-processing

i have many datasets representing different trials of the same test , so they have similar shape but some variance in time and voltage .

[image: example of 2 signals with not aligned rise]

i want a function the will align their rising segment together in the best way approximately. 
i can do this by adding a small constant to x and y of one of the signals and then subtracting it from the other signal and checking when is the smallest mean of that .

the problem with this method is that as you can see in the picture , the critical rise (which i want to align) is occuring in different moment , so i will need to somehow crop the part where the rise occurs.
any ideas how to do that ?

example of what i want to get in the end.

[image: same signals after i roughly manually aligned them]

Comment: Finding and adjusting the heights of each "cluster" should be trivial - just look at the data. As for the point of "rising", that's harder - though once you've found it, translating one of your graphs along the `x` axis should be trivial as well. I would see about taking the time-adjusted average of every set of samples (at about the frequency of a couple of cycles), and look for the moment where the variance is much higher than average

Comment: Do they need to be aligned with sub pixel resolution?

Comment: no they need to be aligned in an approximate way . the result would be a better understanding of the features of this rise .